# C3JS - is there any way to update color.threshold values dynamically on a gauge chart?

Tags: javascript, c3.js

I've been trying to update the colors.threshold value dynamically on gauge chart (c3js) but apparently there's no way to do it via API. Does anybody know how to do it?

I've tried to update the threshold values directly into the chart object instance without any results.

Here's what a sandbox with the attempt:

Codepen: https://codepen.io/felipevega/pen/WBaQKP

```
function updateChart() {
    var randomValue = Math.round((Math.random(100)*100));
    var randomMaxValue = 100 + Math.round((Math.random(100)*100));

    chart.internal.config.gauge_max = randomMaxValue;

    //HERE'S the issue > this is not updating the threshold values
    chart.internal.config.color_threshold = [
      Math.round(randomMaxValue/4), 
      Math.round(randomMaxValue/3), 
      Math.round(randomMaxValue/2), 
      randomMaxValue 
    ];

    chart.load({
        columns: [['Speed', randomValue]]
    });  
}
```

I expect the color.threshold values can be recalculated based on a random max value.

Answer (score 0):

You need two things.

Firstly, wrap your new threshold array in a 'values' property, like in the config, otherwise c3's code won't pick the new values up:

```
chart.internal.config.color_threshold = {values: [
  Math.round(randomMaxValue/4), 
  Math.round(randomMaxValue/3), 
  Math.round(randomMaxValue/2), 
  randomMaxValue 
]};
```

See the code at
https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/ca9fd2b26ef8c2234bb3045589ffe31c625b101a/src/color.js#L31

Secondly, it seems that the gauge uses an internal levelColor function to pick the color rather than the normal color function --> https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/ca9fd2b26ef8c2234bb3045589ffe31c625b101a/src/arc.js#L452

This needs regenerated via the generateLevelColor function (https://github.com/c3js/c3/blob/94cbc06150975cf071b75b9deeec8a6ed27d4484/src/core.js#L95). This in turn needs called with chart.internal as the context so it has access to the internal values.

So:

```
chart.internal.levelColor = chart.internal.generateLevelColor.call (chart.internal);
```

Put them together and the chart now works (non-random version of your codepen here --> https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OeJvjj). Here 35 goes red, where it would have previously been orange.

Comment: Awesome! That was brilliant. Thanks for your help mgraham.